I'm having trouble resolving an email sending error with Spring Boot 3.2.5
I've been implementing an email sending feature using Spring Boot 3.2.5, but I can't seem to resolve an error, so I'm asking for help here
The code and email work fine on other people's computers, but I'm the only one experiencing an error on my computer
First off, the error code looks like this.
I'm using Windows 11 Pro, and it's Gmail on port 587, but the email works fine on other computers
I tried changing the port to 465, but I still encountered the same error. I've also tried using a different network, turning off security programs, and making sure the firewall settings are adjusted to allow for smooth operation, but I'm still facing the same error
Is there anything I might need to adjust to resolve this issue?
I've even tried reinstalling Windows....☹️
org.springframework.mail.MailSendException: Mail server connection failed. Failed messages: jakarta.mail.MessagingException: [EOF]; message exception details (1) are:
Failed message 1:
jakarta.mail.MessagingException: [EOF]
    at org.eclipse.angus.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.issueCommand(SMTPTransport.java:2373)
    at org.eclipse.angus.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.helo(SMTPTransport.java:1666)
    at org.eclipse.angus.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.protocolConnect(SMTPTransport.java:735)
    at jakarta.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:345)
    at org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSenderImpl.connectTransport(JavaMailSenderImpl.java:480)
    at org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSenderImpl.doSend(JavaMailSenderImpl.java:399)
    at org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSenderImpl.send(JavaMailSenderImpl.java:350)
    at org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSender.send(JavaMailSender.java:101)
    at com.docmall.demo.service.EmailServiceImpl.sendMail(EmailServiceImpl.java:54)
    at com.docmall.demo.controller.EmailController.authcode(EmailController.java:48)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:255)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:188)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:118)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:926)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:831)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1089)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:979)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1014)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:903)
    at jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:527)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:885)
    at jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:614)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:150)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:51)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:175)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:150)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:175)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:150)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:175)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:150)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:175)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:167)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:90)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:482)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:115)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:93)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:344)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:391)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:63)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:896)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1736)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:52)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:63)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:840)

I've attempted numerous modifications on my computer with the assistance of various AIs, including ChatGPT, but the same error persists... Please, I need your help.

2nd off where is the code??  Are you trying to send an empty message?

Verify you can connect to gmail server with some other tool like telnet. If connection successful you should have
$telnet imap.gmail.com 587
Trying 173.194.73.108...
Connected to imap.gmail.com.
Escape character is '^]'.
220 smtp.gmail.com ESMTP 38308e7fff4ca-2e95bdd1517sm7621251fa.82 - gsmtp
^]
telnet>q

If there is no connection the command hangs
